# Помогите с легким циклом в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать цикл, который будет из списка фруктов

`fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']` выводить каждое значение и добавлять порядковый номер, чтобы получилось

1. apple
2. orange
3. pineapple

Заранее спасибо, и извините за такую скорее всего легкую задачу для вас.)

Comment: `print(list(map(lambda x: f'{x[0] + 1}. {x[1]}', enumerate(fruits))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
# mark
fruits = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'pineapple' ] 
n = 0
for fruit in fruits : # Перебираем все фрукты и добавляем номер
  n += 1  
  print( str( n ) + '. ' + fruit )
```

Answer (score 1):

есть несколько способов:

через `enumerate`, которая сама добавит последовательно индексы элементам

```
fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']

for obj in enumerate(fruits, 1):
    print(f"{obj[0]}. {obj[1]}")
```

или через обычный проход по индексам:

```
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    print(f"{i + 1}. {fruits[i]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']

for i in range(0, len(fruits)):
    print(i + 1, fruits[i], sep = '. ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно используя генератор решить задачу в одну строку. И тем самым, сэкономить память, если список будет очень большим:

```
fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']

[print(f'{number + 1}. {fruit}') for number, fruit in enumerate(fruits)]
```

Вывод:

```
1. apple
2. orange
3. pineapple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']

for number, fruit in enumerate(fruits,1):
  print(number, fruit)

#1 apple
#2 orange
#3 pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

Чёт совсем примитивный вопрос, индексируй по индексу.

```py
fruits = ["apple", 'orange', 'pineapple']
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    print(" " + str(i+1) + ". " + fruits[i])
```